# Why do we use (void *ptr) in an argument even when we are sure of the type of data we will provide?

Tags: c, pointers, void

I am learning C and in many places I find that people use func(void *ptr) as an argument to a function. I understand that void *ptr is used when you are not sure of the type of data you will send and would like to leave open. The problem is that I see this used in places where, I think at least, the type of data will never change.

For example I was looking at the libcurl API and noticed [this example](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html) to save some the response of a URL request. In the example they created a struct:

```
struct MemoryStruct {
  char *memory;
  size_t size;
};
```

Then they defined a callback function which takes multiple arguments most notable the last argument:

`WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)`

But what's confusing is inside this function definition they created a new variable *mem of type MemoryStruct and casted userp to MemoryStruct.

But why all effort? Since we know we are going to provide a MemoryStruct argument, why couldn't they have written:

`WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, MemoryStruct *userp)`

and do away with the whole void+casting stuff.

I have seen this in other projects as well and I feel like I am missing something as to why void *ptr is being used so often even when it isn't needed...

Comment: Because WriteMemoryCallback is called by another function that does not know that it's a pointer to MemoryStruct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`struct MemoryStruct` cannot be in the declaration of `WriteMemoryCallback` because `WriteMemoryCallback` must be passed to a cURL routine, and cURL does not know anything about `struct MemoryStruct`.

> For example I was looking at the libcurl API and noticed [this example](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html)…

That example passes `WriteMemoryCallback` to `curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);`.

Digging into some header files for cURL, `curl_easy_setopt` is effectively declared as `CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(CURL *curl, CURLoption option, ...);`. So it could accept a pointer to `WriteMemoryCallback` regardless of its type, since `...` will accept any type. However, to make use of that pointer, it must fetch the value passed for the argument, with C’s `<stdarg.h>` features or equivalent, and it must use that value as some function pointer type when making the function call.

In other words, it has some code similar to:

```
// Define the type of the callback function.
typedef size_t Function(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, SomeType *userp);

// Get the pointer to the function the user passed.
Function *Pointer = va_arg(ap, Function *);

// Call the user’s callback function.
Pointer(contents, size, nmemb, userp);
```

Now here is the problem: That `SomeType` above cannot be `struct MemoryStruct` because the cURL source code does not know anything about `struct MemoryStruct`. That structure was defined in the code calling cURL. That code did not exist when cURL was written. There is no way for the cURL author to know what type the user would use.

So the cURL code uses `void` for `SomeType`.

Now, given that, the user could declare `WriteMemoryCallback` to have a parameter of type `struct MemoryStruct *` and then could pass the address of `WriteMemoryCallback` to `curl_easy_setopt`, and `curl_easy_setopt` would use it with a type containing a parameter of type `void *` instead of `struct MemoryStruct *`. That would actually work in many C implementations. However, it is not proper C code. The C standard does not define what happens when you pass a pointer of the former type to a routine that uses it as a value of the latter type. Technically, the pointer types `struct MemoryStruct *` and `void *` could have different representations or even different sizes, and then the call `Pointer(contents, size, nmemb, userp)` would not work. And the two types of pointer-to-function could have different representations and/or sizes, in which case the `va_arg` macro would not work.

Neither of these is generally the case in modern C implementations, but it is allowed by the C standard. So it is generally better to write code that is supported by the C standard, using `void *` both in the cURL code and in the user code.

The person writing that example code knows what type `WriteMemoryCallback` will use, and that is why they can write code in `WriteMemoryCallback` that assigns the pointer to the known type. However, they have to pass `WriteMemoryCallback` through the cURL code, so they cannot use any custom-defined types in its declaration.

Comment: Ok that makes sense thank you, so to summarize libcurl's CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION has no idea what type of argument it will get, I just named mine MemoryStruct but someone could just as easily have written some other struct name and definition. So as not to enforce that we leave it void \*ptr. Also I *could* have made the argument of type MemoryStruct and C would have interpreted it as void *ptr but that would be bad C code as C does not have a strict definition of converting a type void *ptr to another type. This makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's safe, since it does not violate the strict aliasing rule and any pointer that does not point to a cv-quilified type or a function can be converted to `void*` implicitly. It's convenient, for example if you want to sort an array of structs using one of struct fields in `qsort`.

Another example - `fwrite`:

```
int array[10];
fwrite(array, sizeof(int), 10, stdout);
// it does not look well: fwrite((char*)array, sizeof(int), 10, stdout);
```

As for cURL, the callback function is strictly declared as

```
size_t(*)(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
```

and passing the function below with not matching parameters results in undefined  behavior (there are platforms and their compilers where `sizeof(T*)` and `sizeof(void*)` are not equal).

```
size_t WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, MemoryStruct *userp)
```

Comment: Re “any pointer can be casted to `void*` implicitly”: Qualified pointers cannot be converted (not cast) to `void *` implicitly. Pointers to functions cannot be converted to `void *` implicitly. (A cast is an explicit operator in source code; all conversions by cast are explicit. Implicit conversions occur in assignments, such as x = y, and some other places.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil The question is tagged with C, not C++. `void f(char); void *p = f;` is a valid code in C. Compilers do not show any warning at least by default. Pointers to qualified types can cause warnings while conversion and are allowed. See https://godbolt.org/z/vY3WsaW3c

Comment: Re “`void f(char); void *p = f;` is a valid code in C”: C 2018 6.5.16.1 1 specifies the constraints for simple assignment. Only the third and fourth allow assigning one pointer to another. The third allows assigning to a compatible type except that qualifiers may be added, but `void *` and `void (*)(char)` are not compatible types. The fourth allows assigning between `void *` and a pointer to an object type, but `void (*)(char)` is neither…

Comment: … Re “Compilers do not show any warning at least by default”: By default, GCC and Clang do not conform to the C standard. They compile using their own non-standard dialects. With `-std=c18 -pedantic`, they are closer to the standard, and GCC agrees with me: “ISO C forbids initialization between function pointer and 'void *'”.

Comment: Re “Pointers to qualified types can cause warnings while conversion and are allowed”: The same issues as I state above apply: This is not in the constraints for simple assignment, and the compilers issue diagnostics when asked to use standard C.

Comment: `sizeof(void *)` and `sizeof(char *)` must be the same — see C11 [you §6.2.5 Types ¶28](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p28): _A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type._ and footnote 48 which says: _The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions._ See also [§6.3.2.3 Pointers ¶1,7-8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3). Note: a pointer to a function is not a pointer to an object.